# Don't understand when/why to use custom template tags

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am reading a book on django, and it had me create the following custom tag( this is a blog project):

```
from django import template
from .. models import Post


register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag 
def total_posts():
    return Post.published.count()
```

Note I have 4 `Post` objects saved in my db, so now in a template, I can say something like:

```
{% load blog_tags %}
<p>This is my blog. I've written {% total_posts %} posts so far.</p>
```

and it will return:
"This is my blog. I've written 4 posts so far." I just don't understand why I would try and achieve this using a custom template tag. Why not just count the number of `Post` objects in a view and pass it to a template using a context variable? I.e:

```
from .models import Post
def index(request):
 numPosts = Post.objects.count()
 return render(request, 'index.html', {'numPosts': numPosts})
```

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Because you probably do not want to do that in *every* (or a lot of) views.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem You're saying if I wanted to display " I have written X posts so far" in multiple views, I should use the custom tag so I don't have to repeat the logic in the views?

Answer (score 0):

That is a very basic example to show you how to write customs tags.

For the case of `total_posts` (and many others) you can just pass an object context from the view to the template but imagine that to compute the `total_posts` you need to do a lot of queries, for... write a lot of code and you need to use the `total_posts` value in some other templates. The simplest way to do that is to write a custom tag, you will have clearer views and you will repeat much less code.